# Fill in missing row values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe and would like to fill in missing values.

```
mukey   hzdept_r    hzdepb_r    sandtotal_r silttotal_r
425897      0         61        
425897      61        152          5.3         44.7
425911      0         30           30.1        54.9
425911      30        74           17.7        49.8
425911      74        84
```

I want each missing value to be the average of values corresponding to that mukey. In this case, e.g. the first row missing values will be the average of sandtotal_r and silttotal_r corresponding to mukey==425897. pandas fillna doesn't seem to do the trick. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using what I just learned a couple questions below....

FYI, this solution will still leave NaN's for any 'Mukey's that don't have any 'sandtotal_r's or 'silttotal_r's.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()

df1 = df.set_index('mukey')

df1.fillna(df.groupby('mukey').mean(),inplace=True)

df1.reset_index()

    mukey  hzdept_r  hzdepb_r  sandtotal_r  silttotal_r
0  425897         0        61          5.3        44.70
1  425897        61       152          5.3        44.70
2  425911         0        30         30.1        54.90
3  425911        30        74         17.7        49.80
4  425911        74        84         23.9        52.35
```

Comment: Thank you so much Liam, any chance you can have a look at why the code fails on a larger dataset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29359134/pandas-fillna-failing-on-dataset

Answer (score 0):

The pandas [groupBy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method will do what you want. This method allows you to group the elements of a DataFrame by their label and then perform some aggregation function on them.

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()

df1= df.set_index("mukey")

grouped_df = df.groupby("mukey").mean() 

df1.fillna(grouped_df,inplace=True)
```

Setting the [index](https://towardsdatascience.com/pandas-index-explained-b131beaf6f7b#:%7E:text=Index%20is%20like%20an%20address%2C%20that%27s%20how%20any%20data%20point,columns%20its%20general%20column%20names.) to "mukey" is essential. Without this step, the final DataFrame will be unchanged.

Also see [Splitting on Object into Groups](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups) for more info on how to use groupBy.