# When using dataframes as params for .fillna(), is identical shape required?

Tags: python, pandas

According to the Docs, you can use a Dataframe as the value parameter for .fillna()

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

But does the dataframe need to be identical shape?  If so, why does the first example give me the desired output?

Using this df:

```
mukey   hzdept_r    hzdepb_r    sandtotal_r silttotal_r
425897      0         61        
425897      61        152          5.3         44.7
425911      0         30           30.1        54.9
425911      30        74           17.7        49.8
425911      74        84
```

I can run:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df1 = df.set_index('mukey')
df1.fillna(df.groupby('mukey').mean(),inplace=True)
```

and df1 results in the desired df:

```
        hzdept_r  hzdepb_r  sandtotal_r  silttotal_r
mukey                                               
425897         0        61          5.3        44.70
425897        61       152          5.3        44.70
425911         0        30         30.1        54.90
425911        30        74         17.7        49.80
425911        74        84         23.9        52.35
```

However, when I try to run the same code on a larger df, it breaks with InvalidIndexError.

```
df = pd.read_csv('www004.csv')
df1 = df.set_index('mukey')
df1.fillna(df.groupby('mukey').mean(),inplace=True)
```

Error:

```
InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-126-a1038ea351c9> in <module>()
----> 1 df1.fillna(df.groupby('mukey').mean(),inplace=True)

/Users/liamfoley/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in fillna(self, value, method, axis, inplace, limit, downcast)
   2410                                              downcast=downcast)
   2411             elif isinstance(value, DataFrame) and self.ndim == 2:
-> 2412                 new_data = self.where(self.notnull(), value)
   2413             else:
   2414                 raise ValueError("invalid fill value with a %s" % type(value))

/Users/liamfoley/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in where(self, cond, other, inplace, axis, level, try_cast, raise_on_error)
   3306                         not all([other._get_axis(i).equals(ax)
   3307                                  for i, ax in enumerate(self.axes)])):
-> 3308                     raise InvalidIndexError
   3309 
   3310             # slice me out of the other

InvalidIndexError:
```

I can get around that by creating a means_df that has identical shape.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('www004.csv').set_index('mukey')
means = df.groupby(level=0).mean()
means_df = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(df.index),means,
                    left_on='mukey',right_index=True,how='left').set_index('mukey')
df1 = df.fillna(means_df)
```

That gives me the desired result:

```
 df.ix[426184]
        hzdept_r  hzdepb_r  sandtotal_r  silttotal_r  claytotal_r  om_r
mukey                                                                  
426184         0        18         30.1         54.9           15   3.5
426184        18        46         58.2         17.8           24   NaN
426184        46       152          NaN          NaN            5   NaN

df1.ix[426184]
        hzdept_r  hzdepb_r  sandtotal_r  silttotal_r  claytotal_r  om_r
mukey                                                                  
426184         0        18        30.10        54.90           15   3.5
426184        18        46        58.20        17.80           24   3.5
426184        46       152        44.15        36.35            5   3.5
```

Related:
[Pandas fill missing values in dataframe from another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357379/pandas-fill-missing-values-in-dataframe-from-another-dataframe)

[Fill in missing row values in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357785/fill-in-missing-row-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

[In Pandas, how can I patch a dataframe with missing values with values from another dataframe given a similar index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29359134/in-pandas-how-can-i-patch-a-dataframe-with-missing-values-with-values-from-anot)

Comment: Whoops, Now I really know why it's bad to include a link to an external file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround for this could be to use a [transform](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) (rather than an aggregating) groupby method:

```
df1.fillna(df1.groupby(level=0).transform("mean"))
```

*It's unclear to me whether this is a bug in pandas, I recommend posting an issue on Github (it may be a nice feature)!*