# pandas df.fillna - filling NaNs after outer join with correct values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, sharing some columns together.
I'm trying to:

1) Merge the two dataframes together, i.e. adding the columns which are different:

```
diff = df2[df2.columns.difference(df1.columns)]
merged = pd.merge(df1, diff, how='outer', sort=False, on='ID')
```

Up to here, everything works as expected.

2) Now, to replace the `NaN`  values with the values of `df2`

```
merged = merged[~merged.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
merged.fillna(value=df2)
```

And it is here that I get:

```
pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError
```

I don't have any duplicates, and I can't find any information as to what can cause this.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your dataframes with `Nan`'s?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I suppose, that there are some values in the index of the `merged` data.frame that are not in the `df2` data.frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to use a different method - [combine_first()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)
this way, each row with missing data is filled with data from the other dataframe, as can be seen here [Merging together values within Series or DataFrame columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merging-together-values-within-series-or-dataframe-columns)

Answer (score 0):

In case, number of rows changes because of the merge, fillna sometimes cause error. Try the following!

```
merged.fillna(df2.groupby(level=0).transform("mean"))
```

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378852/when-using-dataframes-as-params-for-fillna-is-identical-shape-required)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I still get the same error.